# 4-wire shielded cable for I2C and power

Tags: i2c

I have two PCBs with ATmega328 that will communicate through I2C protocol. The master will also provide power for the slave, which is located at a relatively short distance (30-40cm or 12-16 inches).

Is it feasible to use the same cable for power (3.3V) and communication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Why wouldn't it be? Power is (pretty) static and noiseless.

Just be warned that having the clock and data in the same twisted pair (if your cable has twisted pairs) could cause issues over longer distances. I2C isn't designed for running over cables like that - it's designed for routing round short traces on a PCB.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll give it a try and if something goes wrong, i'll try to find solution for noise mitigation. The thing is that near the cable(10 cm or 4 inches) there is a solenoid powered pump which is the reason i chose a shielded cable.